# Css styling bug on admin controls

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm getting this strange styling bug.

[image]

You can use Firebug or inspect element on the website here: www.leapfm.com but won't be able to see edit, and destroy as that's admin only.

However, the main issue is that when I go into admin. The space between songs stays the same even though there are buttons there. Why is this? and What can I do to fix it?

I tried to fix it with this code (no luck)

```
.admin {
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 350px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's some kind of list order or unordered.
Then how about making it like so:

```
ul li { position: realtive; padding: 0 100px 0 0; } /*where the paddinh must be a little bigger then the admin size*/
ul li .admin { position: absolute; top: 0; right:0; }
```

Comment: ouch no, totally made the app look crazy :)

Comment: Can you paste some of the html for the first 2 lines, from the inspect tool/firebug ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a height property set to *.song* class. 
By defining a height property you make the element always stay in that specific height, regardless of content. The overflow is by default visible, but if you hide the overflow, you will see clipped buttons.

So in order to make your boxes expand automatically when there is more content (i.e. buttons) there, remove the height property.